# Given Length of Array Divide Into N Sections Specifying Start and End Index of Each Piece

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to calculate the the start and end index for of each sub array when dividing a larger array into n pieces.
For example, let's say I have an array of length 421 and I want to divide it up into 5 (relatively) equal parts. Then beginning and ending indices of the five sub arrays would be something like this: [0, 83], [84, 167], [168, 251], [252, 335], [336, 420]. Note that this isn't a homework question. Just worded the problem in more general terms.

Comment: Perhaps it is the time to learn about integer division.

Comment: Note that an array of length 421 has indexes 0 to 420, so that last range should be `[336, 420]`

Comment: @buffjape I have to make that disclaimer because people such as yourself like to make that assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have `n` elements in the array. We want to divide it into `k` parts. Then if `n%k == 0` it's easy enough - every subarray will contain `n/k` elements. If `n%k != 0` then we must uniformly distribute `n%k` among some subarrays, for example the first ones.

To find a start and end index(inclusive) of each consecutive subarray do as follows:

1. Calculate `n % k` as `remainder` to keep track of whether a subarray should be `1` position longer or not.
2. Introduce `2` variables for keeping start and end positions `left` and `right`. For the first subarray, `left = 0`.
3. Calculate `right` as `left + n/k + remainder > 0 : 1 : 0`. Store or print `left` and `right`.
4. Update `left` to a new position `left = right + 1`. Decrement `remainder` as it has just been used.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 until all `k` intervals are created.

Now let's see some sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 421;
    int k = 5;
    int length = n / k;
    int remaining = n % k;
    int left = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        int right = left + (length - 1) + (remaining > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        System.out.println("[" + left + "," + right + "]");
        remaining--;
        left = right + 1;
    }
}
```

**Output**

> [0,84]
>
> [85,168]
>
> [169,252]
>
> [253,336]
>
> [337,420]

Answer (score 2):

The required integer math makes it a bit tricky.  Integer division always truncates but you need to round so the error is distributed evenly.  Integer rounding X / Y is done by adding half of Y, so (X + Y/2) / Y.  The last interval is special, it needs to end at exactly the array length with no regard for rounding.

Encoding this approach in a method:

```
public static int[] Partition(Array arr, int divisions) {
    if (arr.Length < divisions || divisions < 1) throw new ArgumentException();
    var parts = new int[divisions + 1];          
    for (int ix = 0; ix < divisions; ++ix) {
        parts[ix] = (ix * arr.Length + divisions / 2) / divisions;
    }
    parts[divisions] = arr.Length;
    return parts;
}
```

Test it like:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var arr = new int[421];
    var parts = Partition(arr, 1);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < parts.Length-1; ++ix) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,3}..{1,-3}", parts[ix], parts[ix + 1]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Get confident that it works well by checking the edge cases, like Partition(new int[6], 5).  In which case you want one division that is 2 long and the rest is 1.  That works, try some other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of it this way:

If you want to divide **M** elements into **N** parts, then all together the first **x** parts should should have **Math.round(x*M/N)** elements.

If you want to find the start and end of segment **x**, then, you can calculate those directly, because it starts after the first **Math.round((x-1)*M/N)** elements and includes up to the **Math.round(x *M/N)th** element.

Note that I'm not providing formulas for the actual indexes because there are a lot of ways to represent those -- 0 or 1-based, inclusive or exclusive ranges -- and it can be confusing to try to remember the right formulas for different schemes.  Figure it out in terms of the number of elements before the start and to the end, which always applies.

P.S.  You can do that rounding multiplication and division in integer arithmetic like this: **Math.round(x*M / N) = (x * M + (N/2)) / N**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula for both start and end indexes for any sub array.
let say `x` is a size of sub array, then start index of `nth` array will be `(n-1)*x` and end index will be `(n*x-1)`

```
    int arrLength = 424; // your input
    int sections = 5;// your input

    int minSize = arrLength / sections; // minimum size of array
    int reminder = arrLength % sections; // we need to distribute the reminder to sub arrays
    int maxSize = minSize + 1; // maximum size of array 
    int subArrIndex = 1;
    // lets print sub arrays with maximum size which will be equal to reminders
    while (reminder > 0 && subArrIndex <= sections )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SubArray #{0}, Start - {1}, End - {2}", subArrIndex, ((subArrIndex-1)*maxSize), (subArrIndex*maxSize-1)));
        reminder--;
        subArrIndex++;
    }
    // lets print remaining arrays 
    while (subArrIndex <= sections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SubArray #{0}, Start - {1}, End - {2}", subArrIndex, ((subArrIndex - 1) * minSize), (subArrIndex * minSize - 1)));
        subArrIndex++;
    }
```

Output :

> SubArray #1, Start - 0, End - 84
>
> SubArray #2, Start - 85, End - 169
>
> SubArray #3, Start - 170, End - 254
>
> SubArray #4, Start - 255, End - 339
>
> SubArray #5, Start - 336, End - 419